# How to delete contents of present working directory during uninstall in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

I have an application installed in a directory say APP_HOME.
Inside APP_HOME there are files and sub directories.
One of the directory name is **UnInstall** . I have to execute a shell script(uninstall.sh) from UnInstall directory and remove all the files and APP_HOME directory. I want to delete the current directory and the directory previous to this one and all its contents. If I use **rm -rf** from **UnInstall** directory then it not removing the current directory.  Basically I want to remove the current and the previous directory and its content.

Comment: then it throws error..... the error is?

Comment: @Kent  folder is empty error

Comment: Would you please give the full error message?

Comment: Never seen `rm -rf...` say "folder is empty". More info needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file **UnInstaller.sh** executable? 
If not, you can use

```
chmod +x uninstall.sh
```

and then use

```
./uninstall.sh
```

to execute.